# "Can't exec '/usr/bin/make'"... when compiling a framework project

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, frameworks, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a framework (that came as a project folder). When I click Build, I get this:

```
error: can't exec '/usr/bin/make' (No such file or directory)
```

... and sure enough it's not there. How do I resolve this? I am using XCode 4.3.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to [install the command-line tools](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/1006-SW2) from inside Xcode.

If that doesn't fix it, also try doing this in a Terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Comment: Installing command-line tools created the "make" and it builds now, thanks!